# What would you call these illustrations' style? Minimalist?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, illustration, style-identification

They differ quite a lot from the usual flat design minimalist trend, but is still quite a common style? What kind of techniques are being used here?

... and would using Illustrator or vector drawing software be a good way to go about trying to reacreate it?

[image: Alessandro "*Shout*" Gottardo]
Alessandro "*Shout*" Gottardo

[image: Owen Gent]
Owen Gent

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to GDSE, and thanks for your question. It seems your third image didn't get included correctly. You can [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: Hi @PieBie thanks! Unfortunately, I could only add 2 links, but it seems that someone has already tidied up the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look kind of surrealist. I would say the best technique to achieve something like this would be Illustrator for the shapes and Photoshop for the texture and colours because they definitely have a soft grungy quality to them but the lines are clean.